# Having issues setting up GAforflash on Adobe CS4

Tags: flash, google-analytics, flash-cs4

I downloaded [this](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/downloads/detail?name=gaforflash-1.0.1.319.zip) and in the readme the instructions are for CS3, they state:

> 1. If you have Flash CS3 currently open, quit the application.
> 2. Navigate to the location where you unzipped the Google Analytics zip
>      and find the swc (e.g.
>      lib/analytics_flash.swc).
> 3. Create a "Google" directory in one of the following locations    and copy
>      the SWC file there:
>
>    - (Windows) C:\Program Files\Adobe\ Adobe Flash
>        CS3\language\Configuration\Components
>    - (Mac OS X) Macintosh HD/Applications/Adobe Flash
>        CS3/Configuration/Components

Since I have CS4, I found that the directory is different. It is `Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\Components\`

In that directory, I made a directory called `Google` and pasted `analytics_flash.swc` in there.

Afterwards, I restarted CS4 and I don't see any Analytics library.

Did I miss some important step in setting up CS4 so that flash reads from that directory? Or is it supposed to automatically read from there, since it contains core common files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found more up to date instructions in the SVN [readme.txt](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/source/browse/trunk/build/templates/readme.txt?r=395). I also copied the main analytics.swc file in addition.

I was incorrectly assuming it would show up in Window -> Libraries but it should be in Window -> Components.